Error C2988 (unrecognizable template declaration/definition) deducing method return type
I'm getting error C2988 (unrecognizable template declaration/definition), the cursor hinting immediately before the *method parameter.
namespace Bind 
{
    template <typename ModelClass, typename ReturnType>
    static std::unique_ptr<Binding> 
    Get (ReturnType (ModelClass::*method)(),
         const String& source,
         const Symbol& aspect = {})
    {
    // whatever
    return nullptr;
    }

    // ....
}

Example instantiation: Function  WhateverClass::whateverMemberFunction() returns ReturnType and takes no arguments. Both template arguments ModelClass and ReturnType are supposed to be deduced from this instantiation:
Bind::Get(&WhateverClass::whateverMemberFunction, "")

The template compiles fine with Xcode (Apple) but fails with MSVC 2019. Both are using C++17 standard.
What am I missing?

Reduced failing example here.

@user12002570: change default from "" to {} to see the bug Demo

Seems to be a msvc bug to me.

@Jarod42 Yes, I realized that before. MSVC seems to have problem with {} as default when using member function as another parameter. Note that this only happens when there is a  member function pointer parameter. Definitely a msvc bug.

Definitely a msvc bug. Demo

@Anders: As workaround, you might use const Symbol& aspect = Symbol{}

I understand what a minimal reproducible example is (and usually prefer that). But in this case it wouldn't have turned up the solution (see approved answer). Symbol, String and Binding could basically be anything.

This is definitely a msvc bug. MSVC seems to be having problem with using {} as default when one of the parameter is of member pointer type.
Workaround
You can change {} to Symbol{} as shown below:
Get (ReturnType (ModelClass::*method)(), const String& source,
//---------------------vvvvvv---->changed to this    
const Symbol& aspect = Symbol{})
{
 }

Here is the newly submitted msvc bug:
MSVC rejects valid program with {} as default argument when a parameter is of member pointer type

Thanks. Now that even more "Internal Compiler Errors" are popping up, I am reminded that it's never a good idea to rely on a language standard during long stretches of coding a cross-platform project.

@Anders I think you meant "never a good idea to rely on non-portable features" instead of "language standard". Also, your example is already standard conformant and as the bug is with msvc, you don't have to worry about it as you can just use the workaround. You're welcome.
